# Suppressing negative roots in Mathematica

Tags: programming, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

**Problem**

Using Mathematica's `Solve` operator can sometimes lead to an output involving a positive and negative root (say when solving for a variable such as `N^2`.

**What Is Happening**

Here I simply have a defined function `Radial` followed by implementation (`Solve`) of that function.

```
Radial[n_,l_,r_]:= LaguerreL[n-l-1, 2*l+1, ((2*Z)*r)/(n*a)] * ((Z*r)/(n*a))^l Exp[-((Z*r)/(n*a))];
Solve[Integrate[
        N^2 Radial[1,0,r] r^2, 
        {r,0,\[Infinity]},
        Assumptions -> {Z>0,a>0,{Z,a},Reals}
      ]== 1,N]

Out[1]= {{N -> -(Z^(3/2)/(Sqrt[2] a^(3/2)))}, {N -> Z^(3/2)/(Sqrt[2] a^(3/2))}}
```

*Mathematica* is kind enough to give me both positive and negative roots.

**What I Want**

I would like to suppress the negative root, leaving only the positive root solution, i.e. `{N -> (2 Z^(3/2))/a^(3/2)}`

**What I've Tried**

Here I include a couple things I have tried (some suggested by the kind people in chat).

1. Inserting `N>=0` into `Assumptions` : Resulted in two roots.
2. Inserting `N>=0` and `N` into the `Reals` section. : Resulted in two roots.
3. Inserting `&& N>0` following the `==1` combined with all possible permutations of Tries (1) and (2). : Resulted in no answer given (nor any errors).

Hopefully there is a simple way of fixing this (and not some convoluted input syntax).  However, for the benefit of the community, any suggestion is welcomed.  For my particular case, the simpler the better.

Comment: I strongly encourage you not to use N as a variable in Mathematica

Comment: Seconding what Daniel said: try never to use any capitalized names in Mathematica!  Here's a horror story, came in today on MathGroup:  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/QinIGNetTkQ/discussion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is to use [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refine.html) to filter out only the positive root. For example:

```
assume = Z > 0 && a > 0 && n > 0;
int = Integrate[n^2*Radial[1, 0, r]*r^2, {r, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> assume];
sol = Solve[int == 1, n];
If[Refine[(n /. #) > 0, assume], #, ## &[]] & /@ sol
```

[image]

I've changed `N` to `n` since the former is a built-in function. In general, it's good practice in Mathematica to **never** use single capital letters for variables or start functions with capital letters (since internal functions always start with uppercase).

Another way of doing it is by passing the assumptions directly to `Solve`, and getting back only the roots that satisfy those assumptions. However, it has been my experience in the past, with more complicated inequalities, that both `Solve` and `Reduce` tend to choke when you try to impose the requirements of the roots inside it (i.e., it solves the general case faster than the specific), and it's simpler to filter out the general solution with `Refine`.

For the sake of completeness, here's a solution with the constraints inside `Solve` and then further simplified using `Simplify`:

```
Solve[int == 1 && assume, n] // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> assume] &
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass to `Solve` conditions for all three variables. `Solve` cannot decide whether `N` is positive or negative unless it knows the sign of `a` and `Z` , because their values define sign of `N`. Note, passing the assumptions to `Integrate` won't pass them to `Solve` in your implementation. You also do not need to put the integral inside `Solve`. Of course, you may if you'd like to, but I found it separately to be

```
(2 a^3 N^2)/Z^3
```

Plug it in your equation:

```
Solve[(2 a^3 N^2)/Z^3 == 1 && a > 0 && Z > 0 && N > 0, N]
```

Answer

```
{{N -> ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[Z^3/a^3]/Sqrt[2], Z > 0 && a > 0]}}
```

Generally I wouldn't use variable `N` because it is a function in Mathematica and you can run into a trouble.