# Solve ignores assumptions

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I am trying to solve a system of non-linear equations using some easy assumptions. My code is:

```
ClearAll[a, b, x, y, a12, a22]
Assuming[
    {a > 0, b > 0, a12 > 0, a22 > 0},
    Solve[a12 == (x*(x + y))/(a*(a + b)) && a22 == (y*(x + y))/(b*(a + b)) && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Reals]
]
```

Unfortunately Mathematica basically ignores the assumptions and also spits out invalid conditions:

```
{
    {x->ConditionalExpression[
        -(((a a22^2 b^2+a22^2 b^3)/(a a12+a22 b)-a a22 b-a22 b^2)/Sqrt[((a a22^2 b^2+a22^2 b^3)/(a a12+a22 b))]),
        (a>0\[And]a+b<0\[And]a12<0\[And]b<0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a>0\[And]a12>0\[And]b>0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a<0\[And]a+b>0\[And]a12<0\[And]b>0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a<0\[And]a12>0\[And]b<0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a+b>0\[And]a12>0\[And]b<0\[And]a22<0)\[Or]
        (a+b<0\[And]a12>0\[And]b>0\[And]a22<0)],
    y->ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[(a a22^2 b^2+a22^2 b^3)/(a a12+a22 b)],
        (a>0\[And]a+b<0\[And]a12<0\[And]b<0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a>0\[And]a12>0\[And]b>0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a<0\[And]a+b>0\[And]a12<0\[And]b>0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a<0\[And]a12>0\[And]b<0\[And]a22>0)\[Or]
        (a+b>0\[And]a12>0\[And]b<0\[And]a22<0)\[Or]
        (a+b<0\[And]a12>0\[And]b>0\[And]a22<0)]
    }
}
```

I realize that I can get rid of the unneeded solutions by adding the assumptions directly to the Solve command like

```
Solve[a12 == (x*(x + y))/(a*(a + b)) && a22 == (y*(x + y))/(b*(a + b)) && x > 0 && y > 0 && a>0 && b>0 && a12>0 && a22>0, {x, y}, Reals]
```

But the result is still a conditional expression:

```
{
    {x->ConditionalExpression[
        -(((a a22^2 b^2+a22^2 b^3)/(a a12+a22 b)-a a22 b-a22 b^2)/Sqrt[((a a22^2 b^2+a22^2 b^3)/(a a12+a22 b))]),
         b>0\[And]a>0\[And]a22>0\[And]a12>0],
     y->ConditionalExpression[
        Sqrt[(a a22^2 b^2+a22^2 b^3)/(a a12+a22 b)],
        b>0\[And]a>0\[And]a22>0\[And]a12>0]
    }
}
```

I feel like I missed something fundamentally.
Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Try using `Simplify`: `Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, a12 > 0, a22 > 0}, 
 Simplify[Solve[
   a12 == (x*(x + y))/(a*(a + b)) && a22 == (y*(x + y))/(b*(a + b)) &&
     x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Reals]]]`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: [(81004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81004). Similar, but older, answer: [(a/1064)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1064). Related: [(a/23213)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23213).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add assumptions to Solve command](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81004/add-assumptions-to-solve-command)

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

> Assuming[assum,expr] evaluates expr with assum appended to
>   $Assumptions, so that assum is included in the default assumptions
>   used by functions such as Refine, Simplify, and Integrate.

This means that

```
Assuming[assum,Solve[eqn]]
```

is the same as

```
Solve[eqn,Assumptions->assum]
```

But `Assumptions` is not part of the options of `Solve`. Hence, your assumptions are ignored. You can wrap `Solve` with any function that understands `Assumptions`, such as `Simplify`.

Comment: It looks as if `Assumptions` has been added as an option to `Solve` in one of the recent versions.